# Redirect http to https (https works http redirects to default)

Tags: apache, redirect

I have an owncloud setup, and Im trying to make a permanent http redirection to https.

Well my https conf works just fine when i type https://sub.domain.com.
But http://sub.domain.com redirects to debian apache default page.

Im also trying to achieve a proper Strict-Transport-Security HTTP header configuration.

My setup is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.sub.domain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    ErrorLog /var/www/owncloud/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin info@domain.com
        ServerName sub.domain:443
        DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/cloud/sub.domain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/cloud/sub.domain.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/cloud/sub.domain.com.ca-bundle

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                     Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
        </IfModule>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was instead of *:80 on the first line, to use sub.domain.com:80.