# why are my http sites not redirecting to https?

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https

I have been trying to get all of my company's http sites to automatically redirect over to https.

In my httpd.conf file, I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName internal.va.com
  Redirect / https://internal.va.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName internal.va.com
  DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs"
  SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

When using SSLEngine On, restarting apache gives me the following error message:

[image]

When I comment out SSLEngine On, I no longer get the message, but the sites are not redirecting.

Additionally, I am not sure if I should be adding the server IP address in the VirtualHost tags.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost 112.245.154.47:80>
// same info as above
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 112.245.154.47:443>
// same info as above
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not sure if I should be using the server's IP address or if the VirtualHost tag should just include "*:80" and "_ default _:443".

I understand this question may appear to be a duplicate, but I have tried to follow the answers provided under the following questions:

[redirect http to https through httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193829/redirect-http-to-https-through-httpd-conf)

[Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44483830/redirect-http-to-https)

[Redirect http to https (https works http redirects to default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104744/redirect-http-to-https-https-works-http-redirects-to-default)

None of the above questions have helped me solve my problem.  I am still unable to get all of the http sites to redirect over to https.

What can I do to correctly redirect the http sites to https?

Comment: Please check the log files from Apache (specifically error log) which likely point to the cause of the problem.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - What specifically should I be looking for in the error log?

Comment: I found this in the error log: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for internal.va.com:443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName internal.va.com
  DocumentRoot "D:/htdocs"
  SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

> I found this in the error log: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for internal.va.com:443

With the config shown and this error message the problem is pretty obvious: you have SSL enabled but no certificate configured for a host. But HTTPS without a server certificate will not work.

Note that this is completely unrelated to the redirect you are trying to attempt. It is only about configuring a proper HTTPS site.

Comment: How would I go about getting the certificate configured for a host?  Or should I ask a new question?

Comment: @JohnBeasley: You ask essentially the most basic question when starting with SSL: how does one get a certificate and how does one configure it. I recommend that you get first some introduction of what this HTTPS thing is in the first place and how to enable it. This would be too broad to ask here.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for your assistance.